# Fill text box through keyboard events javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I neeed to fill in an input box using keyboard events 'keydown' 'keypress' and 'keyup' for running some test cases .I tried with following code

```
var fireKeyEvent = function(eventType,element,keyCode) {
    var keyboardEvent = jQuery.Event(eventType);
    keyboardEvent.which = keyCode;
    keyboardEvent.keyCode = keyCode;
    $(element).trigger(keyboardEvent);

}
```

i have the following html element

```
<input type='text' id='input'>
```

i tried firing following

```
fireKeyEvent('keydown',$('#input'),49);
fireKeyEvent('keypress',$('#input'),49);
fireKeyEvent('keyup',$('#input'),49);
```

where 49 is the ascii code of 1 so it should insert 1 into the text box.
But it doesnt seem to insert anything into the text box.can someone help?

Comment: `var keyboardEvent = jQuery.Event(eventType);;` there are two semicolons, is this a typo?

Comment: I tried removing the semicolon but still not working @jai